# How to access aws websocket through CloudFront

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-cloudfront

I am following this url to setup cloud front origin.
https://nickzamosenchuk.medium.com/configure-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-for-websocket-connection-43c44b3f877c
How to connect WebSocket through Angular app.?
I tried 2 ways but not able to connect.

```
  let data = this.httpClient.get('https://<id>.cloudfront.net/dev').subscribe(datas => {
      console.log(datas);
    });
```

or

```
this.socket = webSocket('wss://<id>.cloudfront.net/dev');
```

What is the way to connect WebSocket in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, for example:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketExampleService {

  readonly url = "(wss|https)://<id>.cloudfront.net/";

  subject: WebSocketSubject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.subject = webSocket({
      url: this.url,
      deserializer: msg => msg
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not able to connect with WebSocket @YaakovHatam

Comment: What's the error? what you see in the browser console? @user8057332

Comment: DId not get any console error but it's not hitting CloudFront.
Do we need any update in CloudFront origin?